# Two callback functions inside a function not called synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, asynccallback

```
    function sample() {

        var callback_1 = request1(function(response) {

            var Name = response.name;

        });


        var callback_2 = request2(function(response_1) {

                if (response_1.name === Name) {

                    // do something      
                });
        }

}
```

I've two callback functions as shown above, **callback_1 & callback_2** which requests a JSON from the service.

The **callback_2** is called before **callback_1** and variable **Name** is shown as undefined. Any help much appreciated,

How can I let callback_1 executed before **callback_2** so that variable **Name** is not undefined.

Comment: call callback_2 from callback_1... hint: just move the first " });" to behind the last "}"

Comment: `Name` is a local variable to the `callback_1` function.. it will always be undefined.

Comment: @tymeJV Even if Name is global variable, callback_1 is called after callback_2 is executed and hence Name comes as undefined

Comment: @min2bro -- True, but it's still the main problem. Even if callback_1 came back first, it wouldn't matter, can't be accessed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sample() {

    var callback_1 = request1(function(response) {
        var Name = response.name;

        var callback_2 = request2(function(response_1) {
            if (response_1.name === Name) {
                // do something      
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: +1 OP could also make both functions execute asynchronously, then make sure that request1 has finished before comparing request2's result against Name. Doing so is probably needlessly complex for this problem though and would only really be necessary if both requests take a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery ajax request return a deferred object (assumming request1 and request2 are ajax calls of some sort).  Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object.
You can use something along the lines of:

```
function sample() {
    var Name;
    var callback_1 = request1(function(response) {
        Name = response.name;

    });


    callback_1.then(
        callback_2 = request2(function(response_1) {

            if (response_1.name === Name) {

                // do something      
            };
        })
    );

}
```